How do you disable Ubuntu Dock?
Is it ON or OFF?
I've installed and enabled Dash to Panel, and flipped the switch to disable Ubuntu Dock.  Everything works fine...for a while.  And then:  Ubuntu Dock re-enables itself!  Not sure what triggers it, it seems if I ignore it for a few hours it will sneak back on.  You can see from the image that the switch is in the 'Off' position, but it's highlighted.  To disable it again, first need to flip switch 'On', and then back to 'Off'...and the cycle repeats.
If I disable both Dash to Panel and Ubuntu Dock, it stays off, so maybe Dash to Panel is causing UD to re-enable?
GNOME 46.0.1
24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
X86_64

I can confirm that I've had the same for me, although only a restart could get it back to normal. Given my drag'n'drop issue, which may be linked to DiNG.. we may be seeing issues with the extensions on a wider scale.

In addition, I've noticed Ubuntu Dock turning itself back on at times. Using Extension Manager, I turn the manager off an on again and Ubuntu Dock will then turn itself back off.
This seems to be an issue when the system goes into powersave. Perhaps something is not being refreshed when coming out of powersave or defaults are being loaded instead.
